# Beginning statements that end with commas disappear

Tags: bug, editing

Sorry if the title is confusing, but when I try to put some text at the top of the question with a comma ending the line and press "save changes", the text dissapears.

You can watch a video of me trying to write "Hi all," as my starting statement and then watching it dissapear when the changes are saved:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8nGJZi9RcPHRkZMY2NaZUo0d1k/view?usp=drivesdk

A picture is also available:[image: My image]

Comment: *I want to add "hi all" to my post.*  That's exactly what we don't want you to do.  Read the rules (duh).

Answer (score 6):

This is by design. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989)

> We now automatically remove salutations from posts as they are entered.

Comment: OK, I understand now...

Comment: I think the problem is that they appear on the hover summary and render the summary less useful as the first line has only a greeting.